# Login issue with DB2 Database using my local account

Tags: windows, security, db2

I have installed DB2 Express-C in my office machine. This machine does not allow me to create new account, so I installed DB2 using my local login account. Database installed successfully.

But when I try to connect to the database, it always says "Username/Password is invalid".

My local user account has appended with the domain name, for example: "INDDEV/Raghav"

"INDDEV" is the domain name, "Raghav" is my username.

I have tried all the possible combination, but am unable to connect

Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: Please show the exact `connect` statement that produces the error.

Comment: db2 => connect to SAMPLE user raghav using password                                                                     
SQL30082N  Security processing failed with reason "24" ("USERNAME AND/OR
PASSWORD INVALID").  SQLSTATE=08001

Comment: So, is the user "raghav" registered locally or in the domain? Or both?

Comment: I did not register any where, its a domain user. DB2 should have picked this username while installing the DB2 because I have selected the option of local user account.

Comment: Why do you say you are logging in "using my local account" while at the same time saying that "raghav" is a domain user?

Comment: local user account is "raghav". I have installed the DB using using this account, trying to connect using same account. But DB2 is not allowing the same user to login. its a Bug I guess.

Comment: I have installed the DB using the same account, I am trying to connect to the database with the same account, in between I did not alter any configuration related to DB. then why its not allowing me to connect? No other login/user account in my machine. So weird.... Mostly bug from DB2. if its not allowing my account, then which account it will allow.

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from your domain user. DB2 does not recognize by default domain users, thus your user cannot be authenticated. You can create a local user for you, OR you can use the instance user OR change the instance configuration to recognize domain users.

Comment: is there any steps(document) to alter Db2 to recognize domain users?

Comment: Check the documentation: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.sec.doc/doc/c0005897.html http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.sec.doc/doc/c0055077.html

Comment: Documentation you link to states that "to authenticate the user, DB2 checks the local machine first, then the Domain Controller for the current Domain, and finally any Trusted Domains known to the Domain Controller", which contradicts your answer.

Comment: I was not explaining how a user is authenticated. I explained the possible options in order to use DB2. If the DB2_GRP_LOOKUP parameter is not set correctly it will not check the domain. Where my answer is contradictory? BTW, have you tried to use DB2 in Windows with extended security?

Comment: I have installed the DB using the same account, I am trying to connect to the database with the same account, in between I did not alter any configuration related to DB. then why its not allowing me to connect? No other login/user account in my machine. So weird.... Mostly bug from DB2. if its not allowing my account, then which account it will allow